# Equation numbering in pelican with mathjax

Tags: mathjax, pelican

I use `render_math` Pelican plugin to use latex, however it is not (by default) providing equation numbering.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an `eqnarray` latex tag to your equation, as in `$$ \begin{eqnarray} <your equation here> \end{eqnarray} $$`, it will add a numbered equation to the MathJax equation.

(Side note: if it is a multi-line equation, use `\nonumber` to limit the numbering.)